# ServiceM8 api Filter not working

Tags: api, filter

I need to filter JobMaterial for a specific job_uuid.
For some reason despite applying the filter as per the documentation it returns all records.

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobMaterial.json?%2524ffilter=job_uuid%2520eq%[job_uuid]%2522",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic [key]",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));
```

Can someone please help.
Thanks

Comment: Curl URL: https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobMaterial.json?%24ffilter=job_uuid%20eq%20%22[job_uuid]%22

Answer (score 0):

## Check your spelling in the URL.

**Incorrect**:

- ```
  ?%24ffilter
  ```

**Correct**:

- ```
  ?%24filter
  ```

---

**I can confirm this URL works to filter job materials by uuid:**

```
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobMaterial.json?%24filter=job_uuid%20eq%20%u-u-i-d%22
```